# how to use a res.redirect inside of a http.request function

Tags: node.js, http, redirect

```
`var req = http.request(options, function(res) 
       { 
              hh=res.headers["last-modified"]; /* hh is global variable */

       });req.end();
      /*print the last modified time of file that stored in hh
       console.log(hh);
```

How to use hh after getting the value in hh after req.end?

Answer (score 0):

Please do some tutorials on asynchronous code. You don't understand the execution order, which I have highlighted belowe.

```
//this line executes at time T1.1
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  //This line executes at time T2.1, AFTER T1.1 and T1.2 
  hh=res.headers["last-modified"]; /* hh is global variable */
  //This line executes at time T2.2 and hh IS AVAILABLE NOW
  console.log(hh);
});
//This line executes at time T1.2
//hh is NOT SET YET. CANNOT USE IT HERE. This is what async means.
req.end();
```

Comment: I understand the execution order.I know that I have to use console.log(hh) inside the function.But in my actual program I have to use res.render('/show',{msg:'Greater'});But inside the function i cannot use render function.And due to this i cannot show any msg to user.Please help in this incedent.

Comment: Yes, you can use `res.render` inside the `http.request` callback handler function. I'm sorry but your question is not clear enough to me for further comment.